# Best practice translate CakePHP 3.x __ Function

Tags: html, cakephp, internationalization, translation, cakephp-3.x

Using the __('') function is really nice. But I am wondering how can I translate whole paragraphs with links and highlighting in it. For example:

```
<p><?= __('Bla bla text in german bla bla ')?> <a href="/user">Account</a> text bla bla <b>bla</b>.</p>
```

Appart from the link (I know I should use Cake HTML Helper, how to work with this? For translation in diffrent languages it sucks to translate arround these blocks, because the translater sometimes doesnt know the context.

Is this what I am looking for? http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/behaviors/translate.html I am developing in the views - so I am not writing content to the DB with add etc. Maybe this is my first problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Context is what the `__x()` function is there for, it takes an arbitrary context string as the first argument, which is going to be extracted as `msgctxt` when using the I18n shell. That way you can give translaters proper information on what exactly they are translating.

For HTML, well, it depends, and there are personal preferences. Personally I'm usually splitting things up if it's complex HTML, or when I need to use code to generate it. If it's just really basic HTML, or tags that might need to be placed differently in different languages, then I'll keep it in a single message.

In your example I'd do something along the lines of:

```
<?php
$link = $this->Html->link(
    __x('Paragraph XYZ link text', 'Account'),
    ['controller' => 'Users']
);
?>
<p><?= __x('Paragraph XYZ', 'Bla text in german {0} text bla <b>bla</b>.', $link)?></p>
```

When extracting translations, this would end up as something like

```
#: Template/Foo/bar.ctp:3
msgctxt "Paragraph XYZ link text"
msgid "Account"
msgstr ""

#: Template/Foo/bar.ctp:7
msgctxt "Paragraph XYZ"
msgid "Bla text in german {0} text bla bla <b>bla</b>."
msgstr ""
```

With a message that already provides textual context itself, and the `msgctxt` value that complements it, translators shouldn't have problems to figure out what they are translating, and how the messages are related.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Internationalization & Localization > Using Translation Functions](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html#using-translation-functions)**
- **[Cookbook > Shells, Tasks & Console Tools > I18n Shell > Generating POT Files](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/console-and-shells/i18n-shell.html#generating-pot-files)**
- **[API > __x()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.2/function-__x.html)**

Comment: thanks! I will eventually go to translations from DB, but using variables will help me cover that time.